# How to comunicate two Vue.js applications

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Note: this is the function rid that it's being called on the code.

```html
<script>
        const rid = () => "rid_" + Array.from(crypto.getRandomValues(new BigUint64Array(2))).map(item => item.toString(36)).join("");
</script>
```

I'm using vue.js from CDN inside an HTML file, also I'm using jquery to asing Ids to `<app>` elements, something like this:

```html
<app>
</app>
<script>
(function() {
        const app_rid = rid()
        $("app").last().attr("id", app_rid)
        createApp({}).mount("#"+app_rid)
});
</script>
```

In my code I have two of this applications like this:

```html
<!-- #app 1 -->
<app>
</app>
<script>
(function() {
        const app_rid = rid()
        $("app").last().attr("id", app_rid)
        createApp({}).mount("#"+app_rid)
});
</script>

<!-- app #2 -->
<app>
</app>
<script>
(function() {
        const app_rid = rid()
        $("app").last().attr("id", app_rid)
        createApp({}).mount("#"+app_rid)
});
</script>
```

What I want to do, is to call a method of `app #1` from the `app #2` also from other possible apps in the future like `app #3`, `app #4`, etc.

In my code what the `app #1` do is render bootstrap toasts, this is the code:

```html
<component name="toast" class="visually-hidden">
        <div class="toast show" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
                <div class="toast-header">
                        <i class="bi me-2" :class="[icon,'text-'+color]"></i>
                        <strong class="me-auto" :class="['text-'+color]">{{title}}</strong>
                        <small class="me-2">{{time}}</small>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link text-danger-emphasis bi bi-x p-0" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="toast-body">{{message}}</div>
        </div>
</component>
<app>
        <div class="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3">
                <toast-component 
                        v-for="(toast, index) in toasts" 
                        :key="index" 
                        :color="toast.color"
                        :icon="toast.icon"
                        :title="toast.title" 
                        :time="toast.time" 
                        :message="toast.message"
                />
        </div>
</app>
<script>
        const rid = () => "rid_"+Math.random().toString().substring(3)
        (function() {
                const app_rid = rid();
                const toast_component_rid = rid();
                $("app").last().attr("id", app_rid);
                $("component[name=toast]").last().attr("id", toast_component_rid);
                createApp({
                        data: function() {
                                return {
                                        toasts: []
                                }
                        },
                        components: {
                                'toast-component': {
                                        props: ['color', 'icon', 'title', 'time', 'message'],
                                        template: '#'+toast_component_rid
                                }
                        },
                        methods: {
                                AddToast(toast) {
                                        this.toasts.push(toast);
                                        setTimeout(() => {
                                                this.toasts.shift();
                                        }, 5000);
                                }
                        },
                        mounted() {
                                this.AddToast({
                                        'color': 'primary',
                                        'icon': 'bi-alarm',
                                        'title': 'hello world',
                                        'time': '0ms',
                                        'message': 'toast content here'
                                })
                        }
                }).mount("#"+app_rid)
        })();
  </script>
```

What I want is to call the method `AddToast()` of this app from the other apps.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered how to do this, I have to define the createApp `app #1` as a public variable, then i can call to its methods, firstly I change this:

```html
<app>
</app>
<script>
let app1;
(function() {
        const app_rid = rid()
        $("app").last().attr("id", app_rid)
        app1 = createApp({
                methods: {
                        Example() {
                        }
                }
        }).mount("#"+app_rid)
});
</script>
```

Then I can call to it's methods like this:

```
app1.Example();
```

Also I saw that I could refactor the app id definition with this simpler code:

```js
$("app").last().attr("id", rid())
createApp({}).mount("#"+$("app").last().attr("id"))
```

That way It's not needed to define them on anonymous functions.